# javascript past date alert

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put an alert to my input below when I pick a past date and I want it to give a warning like "past date, please enter a valid date"
How can I make this with javascript ?

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" required>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Could you disable previous dates? Looks like you can set a min available date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Wonder if you could do something like:

```
<input type="date" min={Date.now()} required>
```

Might be worth checking out the MDN docs for ways to format the Date to YYYY-MM-DD format.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: thank you, I will try and check the document

Answer (score 0):

Take the date from the user in the date variable.
Generate the current date using the javascript object.

var today = new Date();

now check with the given date entered by the user.

if(today_date > user_entered_date)
alert("Please enter a valid date. The date has expired.");